# MYSQL infile concat

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wamp

i tried to refer to the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

```
ID1, ID2, ID3, Date, Time, plateNumber, ID4, Status
1   7   1   2017-08-15  11:18:00    SGA7387T    97871   1
```

That's my text file

My database is.

```
ID1, DateTime, ID2, ID3, PlateNumber, ID4, Status.
```

My SQL statement

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/table/text/trip.txt'
into table trip FIELDS terminated by '\t'
lines terminated by '\r\n' 
ignore 1 lines
(ID1, ID2, ID3, @DATE, @TIME,plateNumber, ID4,Status) 
SET DateTime = CONCAT(@TripDate,@tripTime);
```

No error but 0 insert...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should edit your txt-file. There must be the same field separators - in header, in data. For example ',' -

```
ID1,ID2,ID3,Date,Time,plateNumber,ID4,Status
1,7,1,2017-08-15,11:18:00,SGA7387T,97871,1
```

Then, there is a problem with different variable names, @DATE vs. @TripDate, and @TIME vs. @tripTime.

At the end, if DateTime is type of DATETIME, then you should convert string to this type.

So, here it is a result query -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/table/text/trip.txt'
into table trip FIELDS terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\r\n' 
ignore 1 lines
(ID1, ID2, ID3, @DATE, @TIME, plateNumber, ID4, Status) 
SET DateTime = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@DATE, ' ', @TIME), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

Do not forget about LOCAL keyword if file is located on client host.