# Conversion of mm:ss to hh:mm:ss in sql in creation of table

Tags: sql, time

I am learning SQL and I am facing an issue. I have a csv file which contains duration of song in a "m:ss" format. However, I didn't quite understand how I could automatically convert them to the "hh:mm:ss" format to store them in my table.

For the moment my table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SONG` (
  `DURATION` TIME NOT NULL
)
```

then I load my csv file but there is an issue due to the format of time requiring the hours.

I would like to be able to load for example 3:49 and to have it as 00:03:49 in the table.

Is there a way to parse these m:ss to hh:mm:ss ?

Any help would be appreciated

Solution:
Thanks to Bren's answer and this question ( [MYSQL infile concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202363/mysql-infile-concat) ) I was able to find a solution.

I kept my creation of table the same, but changed the loading to : LOAD DATA INFILE '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/Song.csv' INTO TABLE `SONG` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (@MINSEC) SET `DURATION` = CONCAT('00:0', @MINSEC);

Comment: What are you using to load the CSV file?

Comment: @Kevin I used LOAD DATA INFILE '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/Song.csv' INTO TABLE `SONG` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (WHen it comes to date/time, many products have their own functions.)

Comment: BTW, use an interval data type instead for duration. Time is the value of the clock.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate.

For example :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SONG` (
`DURATION` TIME NOT NULL
--  DURATION VARCHAR(50)
);
SET @time_field_in_csv = '03:49';
-- used directly gives wrong result
INSERT INTO SONG VALUES ( @time_field_in_csv );
INSERT INTO SONG VALUES (CONCAT ( '00:' , @time_field_in_csv));
SELECT * FROM SONG;
```

The output shows that only the second `INSERT` has worked correctly.

```
DURATION
03:49:00 
00:03:49
```

**NB The syntax for concatenation depends on the Datebase used.**